# cat't show any data using Inner join query

Tags: php

I am using an inner join of two tables first table name inventory and second table name is child_category unique field p_id. this code is not working.

```
<?php
    $inventory_id= $_GET['inventory_id']; 
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM inventory inner JOIN   child_category ON inventory.p_id = child_category.p_id  inventory_id='$inventory_id'");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        ?>
```

Comment: You're missing `where` Run this query and before querying check it on mysql console too.  `SELECT * FROM inventory inner JOIN   child_category ON inventory.p_id = child_category.p_id  where inventory_id='$inventory_id'"`

Comment: PS, JOIN, and INNER JOIN is the same thing.

Comment: You forgot to add `WHERE` clause in your query

Comment: Missing an `AND` or an `OR` too `inventory.p_id = child_category.p_id  inventory_id='$inventory_id'`  Should be `inventory.p_id = child_category.p_id  AND inventory_id='$inventory_id'` etc.

Comment: SELECT * FROM inventory where inner JOIN   child_category ON inventory.p_id = child_category.p_id  inventory_id='$inventory_id

Comment: @amit - that is totally wrong, your WHERE is before you JOINs, and there is no `AND` as I mentioned.  `SELECT * FROM inventory JOIN child_category ON inventory.p_id = child_category.p_id AND inventory_id='$inventory_id `  It's ambiguous as to what your Joining On and if that should be part of WHERE or not.  And you have SQLInjection vulnerabilities too.  Yea!

Comment: SELECT * FROM inventory  JOIN   child_category ON inventory.p_id = child_category.p_id AND inventory_id='$inventory_id "not workiing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check p_id column is exist in both table?
if yes then replace on with where
at ON inventory.p_id = child_category.p_id

Comment: SELECT * FROM inventory  JOIN  child_category ON inventory.p_id = child_category.p_id OR inventory_id='$inventory_id